# If $Z = X+Y$, when do $F_Z(z) = F_X(z)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Z = X+Y$, $X$ and $Y$ independent with $\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$, but $Y$ is nondegenerate. Given
$$ F_W(w) := \mathbb{P}(W \leq w), $$
is there a value $c$ such that
$$ F_Z(c) = F_X(c)$$
?

Comment: Y=0 works.  Anything else in mind?

Comment: it's true if $Y = 0$ with probability 1. Perhaps the condition is something like $P( a< Y <b ) = 0$  if $(a,b)$ doesn't contain $0$; but that sounds the same as $Y=0$ with probability 1. So, think of a uniform continuous distribution on [$a, b$), then you transform it to 0 if that variable is in $(a,b)$, but 1 if it took value $a$.

Comment: Is there anything else to be said besides $Y=0$? I edited the question to exclude and clarify this.

Comment: The condition is equivalent (apart from changing $Y\rightarrow -Y$) to: $E[F_X(c+Y)]=F_X(c)$. Maybe this helps.

Comment: For example if $F_X$ is linear around c and the support of Y is inside this linear range the equality is respected. Indeed in this case we have: $F_X(c+Y)=F_X(c)+\alpha Y$ and $E[F_X(c)+\alpha Y]=F_X(c)$.

Comment: This is just to show that there are non-trivial cases for wich a $c$ exists. It does not answer though if such a $c$ always exists